# oozie3.3.2 Build failure while mkdistro.sh command execution

Tags: maven, hadoop, oozie

I Getting `oozie 3.3.2` from `apache.package.org`. I can't installed `oozie3.3.2` in my system. but I have installed maven in my system.

```
**Maven version :Apache Maven 2.2.1
Java version: 1.7.0_55**

$/oozie/bin$ ./mkdistro.sh -DskipTests
This line is not executed...... 


Detailed Error which i am getting

**[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Project 'org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop' is duplicated in the reactor
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Fri May 02 15:49:31 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/117M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed.**
```

Comment: Why have you installed such an [old version of Maven](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html) ? So there is a real problem with the build of oozie, cause the failure message `org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop' is duplicated in the reactor` produces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [system requirements](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_QuickStart.html#System_Requirements%3a) specify the necessary version:

```
Maven 3.0.1+
```

The [mailing list confirms this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-oozie-users/201206.mbox/%3CCC050F77.56B3%25virag@yahoo-inc.com%3E):

```
Maven 3 is required for oozie 3.2.
```